# How do I set up a CI/CD pipeline using AWS CodePipeline for a Flask application deployed using Zappa?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline, continuous-delivery, zappa

I need a step by step guide on setting up a CI/CD pipeline using AWS CodePipeline for a Flask application deployed using Zappa.

Zappa is an open source framework that helps in building and deploying server-less, event-driven Python applications particularly WSGI web applications like Django and Flask applications on AWS Lambda and API Gateway. The GitHub repository for Zappa can be found at https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some general guidelines that should assist you with your task.

1. Use [Pipenv](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for your project and install all packages via `pipenv install` command
2. Install Zappa on your pipenv env. using `pipenv install zappa`
3. Run `zappa Init` to create the *zappa_settings.json* file
4. Edit and configure your *zappa_settings.json* according to your project requirements.
5. IMPORTANT - you will have to specify the AWS key & secret directly to the pipeline.
   For this purpose make sure you **delete** the *profile_name* key
   from the *zappa_settings.json* and provide them via the pipeline Keystore settings.
6. Run the first `zappa deploy` and confirmed everything runs smoothly.
7. configure the pipeline to retrieve changes automatically from your repository and deploy it [official python docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python)
8. Add the following lines to your *buildspec.yml* file:

   ```yaml
   commands:
       - pip install pipenv
       - pipenv install
       - pipenv run zappa update
   ```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

prerequisites:
Inlocal machine do zappa init which will create zappa_settings.json file. you can modify zappa_settings.json according to your requirements.
include zappa_settings.json and requirements.txt in the root directory

- use docker image for python example "frolvlad/alpine-python3"
- apk add build-base
- apk add python3-dev
- pip install pipenv
- pipenv run pip install -r requirements.txt(where u can specify the packages to be installed along with their version)
- pipenv run zappa deploy --all(or any environment you have specified in zappa_settings.jsonfile) || pipenv run zappa update --all